# Can I create a HtmlHelper specifically for IEnumerable properties?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, html-helper

I would like to create a HtmlHelper that can be used on IEnumerable properties.

The aim is to use it like this:

```
@Html.DisplayForEnumerable(m => m.EnumerableItemsProperty, "ViewTemplateName");
```

If possible I would like to use the `m => m.Items` lambda syntax (as opposed to passing through `Model.Items`).

This is my best effort so far. But I'm not sure how to get the `items` variable from the expression parameter.

I suspect I may have to use something like `IEnumerable<TValue>` as the return type of the expression, but I'm quite new to generics and I've no idea how to implement this.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayForEnumerable<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable>> expression, string templateName, object additonalViewData = null)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    // how to get items variable?

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var item1 = item;
        sb.Append(html.DisplayFor(m => item1, templateName, additonalViewData));
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

**Update**

To clarify - I am taking this approach because I would like to be able so specify differnt templates for the same model.  And the normal `DisplayFor()` enumeration does not occur if you specify a particular template.

I know I could just enumerate through manually, but I'd rather use this method unless someone more knowledgable advises otherwise.

Comment: MVC already has this. Its just `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EnumerableItemsProperty)` and you create an `EditorTemplate` for the type that is used in your collection.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I would like to be able to use various templates if possible, and the automatic enumeration does not occur if you specify a particular template. I know I could just enumerate through manually, but I took a fancy to doing it this way.  Would you advise against this?

Comment: Not sure what your mean. If you have a model say `Person.cs` then you create an `EditorTemplate` - `/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml` then the `DisplayFor()` method will generate the correct html for each `Person` in the collection. If you want different templates associated with different controllers, then you can put them in the `/Views/yourControllerName/EditorTemplates` folders

Comment: Sorry. I mean I'd like to be able to specify different templates for the same model. For example "AsPanel", "AsListGroupItem", etc.

Comment: You want 2 different templates for the same object within the same controller?

Comment: Yeah. One might have more detail and controls than another.

Comment: I think you will find this far easier if you use view models (say `Person.cs`and `AssociatedPerson.cs` and create an `EditorTemplate` for each view model. But if you really want to do this I can add an answer.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  I will take your advice, but I'd still like to know how to do this, if you don't mind.

Comment: Need a break, but will add an answer,(including my recommendations) in about an hour.

Comment: No problem, and thank you.  It's 2am UK time so I'm pretty much out of steam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You helper will need to be

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayForEnumerable<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string templateName, object additionalViewData = null)
{
    ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    IEnumerable collection = metaData.Model as IEnumerable;
    if (collection == null)
    {
        return helper.DisplayFor(expression, templateName, additionalViewData );
    }
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        html.Append(helper.DisplayFor(m => item, templateName, additionalViewData).ToString());
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
}
```

Note the code allows you to pass either a single `T` or `IEnumerable<T>` (although the method name now does not really make sense). If you wanted to limit it to only `IEnumerable<T>` you could throw an `InvalidCastException` if `collection == null`

Note that this approach will not work if you wanted to generate form controls for a collection (for example a `EditorForEnumerable()` method) because the required collection indexers will not be added to the generate `name` attributes. A better approach is to use the built-in `DisplayFor()` and `EditorFor()` methods which will generate the correct html for both `T` and `IEnemerable<T>`

Assuming you have a `Person.cs` class, create a partial view in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Person.cshtml` (note the name of the file must match the name of the class) and in the view simply use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.yourCollectionProperty)
```

You can also create specific display and editor templates for each controller, for example `/Views/yourControllerName/DisplayTemplates/Person.cshtml`. This allows you to use one template in `/Persons/Index` and another template in `/Organisation/Details/1` which might display a list of `Person` associated with an `Organisation`

And finally, if you do need 2 different templates for `Person` in the same controller, you can use view models, for example `class PersonVM` and `class AssociatedPersonVM` and create an `EditorTemplate` for each

Comment: That's a model answer, loads of info - thanks a million.